# Google Map Show blank Map

Tags: google-maps, api-key

help me please... 
for a very long time i have a problem.
i was made android application which implemnet google maps with eclipse. I have following a lot of tuorial from google. All of them failed. After I installed in my device, program just showing blank white map with only zoom control and sign google. I was put all of permission needed in my manifest, i have my apikey which i get from my SHA1. I got my SHA1 from windows - preference - android - build. I also tried to get my SHA1 from commandprompt and have the same result. Android google map v2 was switch on.

somebody, help me please.. whats wrong with my program..

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem, in my case it was due to API KEY it was not correct. I regenerated key with SHA1 and problem solved.

[This link has sample code you can download and check](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/showing-current-location-in-google-maps-using-api-v2-with-supportmapfragment/)

Comment: thanks for reply,
finally my problem solved. So, my mistake is i always create apk using new keystore. After I try to use debug.keystore in users/.andrid/debug.keystore, my maps working fiine. 
I think because i get my SHA1 using debug.keystore

Answer (score 0):

You must get API key from Google Console by the link that provide into google_api.xml in android when create map activity in android studio.
so you copy API Key from google console and past into google_api.xml where YOURKEY HERE.After you must go to Google Console and enable key so it will work.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was an existing app that I cloned from GitHub.
What worked for me is to enable the SHA-1 of my signing certificate. Follow these [short instructions](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth).

Then I had the main developer add my SHA-1 fingerprint to the authorized packages for his relevant API Key [here](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials?) (in his login). Then it worked.